# Reference JS array in D3 Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, d3.js

I am using [this version of a D3 stacked bar chart](https://gist.github.com/mstanaland/6100713).

Currently, when  the user hovers over a segment of a bar, a tooltip shows the value of the active segment.

However, I would like to add html that shows a list of the values of all the segments in the single bar (and maybe highlight the active one).

How do I reference this data from the array? The code currently uses d.y to grab the current segment's value, but what about the others?

I'd like to use .html, but I have no idea how to access/reference/call the data for the other segments.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3qrd3z7/)

Here's an idea of what I'd like to do:

```
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
        var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
        var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
        tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
        tooltip.select("text").text("$"+(d.y).toLocaleString())
        .html("FIRST LINE <br> SECOND LINE HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO PUT OTHER DATA FROM ARRAY");
      });
```

Here is what the array looks like

```
var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2009", redDelicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2010", redDelicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2011", redDelicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" },
  { year: "2012", redDelicious: "04", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "8", pears: "1" },
  { year: "2013", redDelicious: "06", mcintosh: "11", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2014", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "13", oranges: "9", pears: "5" },
  { year: "2015", redDelicious: "16", mcintosh: "19", oranges: "6", pears: "9" },
  { year: "2016", redDelicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" },
];
```

**EDIT:** Or, is there a way to just get the active segment's ID/key instead of all the segments?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Fiddle, it looks like you are grouping the apples according to type, which looks to be causing your issue.

If you were to group (`<g>`) columns by year (group of 2011 apples, 2012 apples, etc) rather than having them grouped by type of apple (red delicious apples, mcintosh apples, etc) you would have access to the data for each column and could then show the relevant information.  In this way, the grouping would closely resemble how your data is structured, and you will have access to the information you need to present either all of the information for that year, or just display the information relevant to that particular segment.

This is called "nesting" according to the [d3js](http://d3js.org) website.  Mike Bostock (the creator of d3) has an [excellent article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) on understanding nesting and how to use it to meet your needs.

Mike Bostock has an excellent example of using this technique [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208)